# Introspect a method reference in "::" double-colon notation?

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose I have a bunch of classes with methods, for example

```
class A {
   public void foo();
}
```

can a function be written in another class...

```
public String getMethodName(Function<?> func) { ... }
```

which when called with any method reference, for example

```
String val = getMethodName(A::foo);
```

would return the name of the method as a String, in this example `"foo"`?

Comment: May I ask why if you wouldn't just use the [`getName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getName()) on `foo`? What is the context of this code?

Comment: No. If you're looking to get the name of a method at runtime, you'll need to use reflection.

Comment: You already know the method name, as you are passing it as a param! Why not just make a string of that name only???!!!

Comment: @Ketan That approach has disadvantages (though it's the best you can do in Java). For instance, if you rename the `foo` method, the static type compilation will not complain if you forget to change the string.

Comment: @yshavit thank you for understanding my requirement. I am looking to obtain a compile-time, static binding to the method name.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible thru bytecode decompilation because

```
foo(Baz::bar)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
class SomeFakeName implement Interface {
   public void methodName() {
        Baz.bar();
   }
}

foo(new SomeFakeName())
```

I assume following declarations:

```
void foo(Interface p){}
interface Interface {
    void methodName();
}
```